# Check if date is this date or bigger

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I trying to check if a date is this date or bigger inside my linq query with boolean. But it's not working like i want.

This my code

```
        public bool CheckMonth(int month)
    {
            if (month > System.DateTime.Now.Month)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (month == System.DateTime.Now.Month)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
    }

    public virtual IList<DateItem> GetThreeDateToList()
    {
        var data = new ScoutDataDataContext();

        var q = (from d in data.DateDetails
                 where d.Activate == 1 && CheckMonth(d.EndDate.Month) 
                 orderby d.Date.Date.Month descending
                 select new DateItem
                 {
                     Title = d.Title,
                     Date = d.Date.Date + " - " + d.EndDate.Date,
                     Link = d.Link,
                 }).Take(3);

        return q.ToList();
    }
```

Anyone who nows a diffrent way?

Comment: not the biggest part of your problem, but CheckMonth can be written

    public bool CheckMonth(int month)
    {
        return month >= System.DateTime.Now.Month;
    }

Comment: It would be helpful to know what it is doing and what you want it to do? Is it throwing exception? Wrong Value?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What is it that you want to do? According to your text you want to find out whether a given date is today or later, but the code sample compares only the month (which means that June this year is the same as June last year). If you want to compare the date (including year and day), this comparison will do the job for you:

```
yourDate.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the provider here? LINQ-to-SQL? Objects? Entity Framework? (from the name, it looks like LINQ-to-SQL...)

Indeed, database providers won't be able to process your method; you have a few options:

- inline it: `&& d.EndDate.Month >= System.DateTime.Now.Month`
- map it to a UDF (LINQ-to-SQL only) that accepts a `DateTime`

The first is probably easier... if you get problems with it not recognising System.DateTime.Now.Month, then do that first into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is only checking that the month is greater than the current month, so July 4th, 1776 would pass. I assume you want to check the entire date?  Do this:

```
    var q = (from d in data.DateDetails
             where d.Activate == 1 && d.EndDate > DateTime.Now) 
             orderby d.Date.Date.Month descending
             select new DateItem
             {
                 Title = d.Title,
                 Date = d.Date.Date + " - " + d.EndDate.Date,
                 Link = d.Link,
             }).Take(3);
```

A couple of other points:

```
        if (month < System.DateTime.Now.Month)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (month == System.DateTime.Now.Month)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Is the same as:
  return month >= System.DateTime.Now;

I should say almost the same, since you are unecessarily calling DateTime.Now twice, and you might end up with separate values.  Call DateTime.Now once and place it in a variable to ensure that you are consistently checking the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to compare two Dates against each other. It works pretty much the same as `DateTime.Compare` but for Date strings.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This lets you compare two dates (dd/MM/yyyy) - the first against the second - 
    /// returning an integer specifying the relation between the two.
    /// If 1, then the first date is greater than the second; 
    /// if 0, then the first date is equal to the second; 
    /// if -1, then the first date is less than the second.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Date1">The first date in string format: dd/MM/yyyy</param>
    /// <param name="Date2">The second date in string format: dd/MM/yyyy</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// 1 : The first date is greater than the second. 
    /// 0 : The first date is equal to the second. 
    /// -1 : The first date is less than the second.
    /// </returns>
    public int CompareDates(string Date1, string Date2)
    {
        try
        {
            string separator_value = "/";

            string[] date1_parts = Date1.Split(separator_value.ToCharArray());
            string[] date2_parts = Date2.Split(separator_value.ToCharArray());

            // 0 : Day
            // 1 : Month
            // 2 : Year

            if (string.CompareOrdinal(date1_parts[2], date2_parts[2]) > 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (date1_parts[2] == date2_parts[2])
            {
                if (string.CompareOrdinal(date1_parts[1], date2_parts[1]) > 0)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (date1_parts[1] == date2_parts[1])
                {
                    if (string.CompareOrdinal(date1_parts[0], date2_parts[0]) > 0)
                    {
                        return 1;
                    }
                    else if (date1_parts[0] == date2_parts[0])
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Here are three examples showing the three forms of validation in action:

```
// Is Date-1 greater than Date-2?
if (CompareDates("17/07/2019", "14/07/2019") > 0) // Returns true.
    return true;
else
    return false;

// Is Date-1 less than Date-2?
if (CompareDates("17/07/2019", "14/07/2019") < 0) // Returns false.
    return true;
else
    return false;

// Is Date-1 equal to Date-2?
if (CompareDates("17/02/2019", "14/07/2019") == 0) // Returns false.
    return true;
else
    return false;
```